# Trying to start service in postgres-14 but failed at postmaster execution

Tags: postgresql, server

```
[root@server ~]# systemctl status postgresql-14.service
● postgresql-14.service - PostgreSQL 14 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql-14.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/postgresql-14.service.d
           └─override.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2022-07-12 03:58:25 UTC; 4min 8s ago
     Docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/static/
  Process: 4707 ExecStart=/usr/pgsql-14/bin/postmaster -D ${PGDATA} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 4702 ExecStartPre=/usr/pgsql-14/bin/postgresql-14-check-db-dir ${PGDATA} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4707 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 12 03:58:25 server systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL 14 database server...
Jul 12 03:58:25 server systemd[1]: postgresql-14.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 12 03:58:25 server systemd[1]: postgresql-14.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 12 03:58:25 server systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL 14 database server.
```

Comment: As always: try to start it with `pg_ctl` (see the documentation for details) and look at the error.

Comment: Look in PostgreSQL's log file.